# Extracting a string to the left of parenthesis within a cell in a dataframe column

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split

I have the following dataframe example:

```
names = ['Banana, Andrew Something (Maria Banana)', 'Willis, Mr. Bruce (Demi Moore)', 'Crews, Master Terry']

room = [100, 330, 212]

hotel_loon = {'Name' : Series(names), 'Room' = Series(room)}

hotel_loon_df = DataFrame(hotel_loon)
```

The names inside the parenthesis are the actual occupants of the hotel room, the name outside of the parenthesis is the name of the person that made the reservation. If there is just a single name like the case of Terry Crews he both reserved the hotel and is the room occupant.

I was able to extract the title from the name string:

```
for i in hotel_loon_df:
    hotel_loon_df['Title'} = hotel_loon_df.Name.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)\.')
```

but I am blocked on how to proceed in extracting the name inside the parenthesis to be its own column.

If you have any insight or suggestions on how to proceed I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would expect that something like this would help you: 
`(\w+), (?:([A-Za-z]+)\. )?([\w]+)(?: ([\w]+))?(?: \(([\w ]+)\))?` https://regex101.com/r/EK4lUa/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
# get everything inside brackets
hotel_loon_df['occupants'] = hotel_loon_df['Name'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')

# get outside of brackets
hotel_loon_df['persons'] = hotel_loon_df['Name'].str.extract('(.*?)\(.*?\)')
```